# Is it possible to set a fallback shell for the user?

Tags: command-line, system

This is probably not the best setup, but just assume that it is part of an experiment.

Into my system `/etc/shells` I added a custom shell

```
/home/myuser/.nix-profile/bin/fish
```

I can then use `chsh` to change the login shell of `myuser` and set it to the Fish shell provided by Nix.

Is there a way to fallback to `bash` if the Nix Shell is not present?

In other words, can a system shell be set as the default option in case the user's shell is inaccessible or fails to start?

I want to avoid a situation where, for whatever reason, the Fish shell provided by Nix is not accessible and `mysuser` cannot login into the system.

Comment: Have you considered creating a backup user instead?

Comment: Back in the days before setuid chsh was a thing, we'd change our own "login" shells by exec'ing them from our ~/.profile. That would allow you to test for the existence / executabilty of your custom shell before committing. How to do that cleanly in the modern age (where /etc/profile conditionally pulls in /etc/bash.bashrc) would take careful consideration.